# How to convert selenium.webdriver.get_cookies() to cookie text file for use with pycurl

Tags: python, selenium, curl, cookies

selenium.webdriver.get_cookies() gives me two dictionaries of value/pairs. I assume each of these dictionaries is a cookie. How do I write these cookies to a text file that will work with the following code to load the cookies from the cookie.txt file to a curl session?

```
p = pycurl.Curl()
cookiefile = open('cookie.txt', 'r')
p.setopt(pycurl.URL, my_url)
p.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, cookiefile)
p.perform()
```

Is there a better way to transfer the cookies from a selenium session to a curl session for a file download? I saw the post about using pickle, but using the file produced by pickle.dump() as cookiefile in the above code results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: invalid arguments to setopt
```

I think this is because the file is just a binary dump of the python dictionary and not a properly formatted text file. How can I write these two dictionaries to a text file that can be read and used by pycurl? I found some information in RFC6265:

> Each cookie begins with a name-value-pair, followed by zero or more
>   attribute-value pairs.

Each dictionary from selenium.webdriver.get_cookies() has a name and value attribute along with other attributes. How do I format these into a properly formatted cookie.txt file? I am not sure about the syntax description in RFC6265:

```
set-cookie-header = "Set-Cookie:" SP set-cookie-string
set-cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-av )
cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
...
path-av           = "Path=" path-value
```

So would it start like

```
Set Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4jqhjdiq9k12ry45ahqtux3e (path=/; secure=False; httpOnly=True; domain=www.domain.com)
```

and then another line starting with Set Cookie: and the second dictionary's name and value followed with its additional attributes in parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Everything I have found since asking this question points to the answer to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36531/format-of-cookies-when-using-wget, being the answer to my question as well (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html says curl uses the netscape cookie format).

Answer (score 0):

## Use this code

I used requests, not pycurl, but I think this will help you a little.

```
cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
cookies_dict = []
for cookie in cookies_list:
    cookies_dict.append([cookie['name'],cookie['value']])
cookies_dict = dict(cookies_dict)
```

and

```
requests.get(URL, cookies=cookies_dict)
```

this will work.